# How to create self-referencing many-to-many field in peewee?

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm using the peewee Python ORM for the first time (Postgresql with Playhouse module), and I want to do the following:

`class Person(BaseModel):
    followers = ManyToManyField(rel_model=Person, related_name='following')`

But I get a NameError because Person is not defined when I try to use it as an argument. Is there a clean way to do what I want with a ManyToManyField, or do I just need to create a separate junction table as if the ManyToManyField feature didn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
class Person(Model):
    name = TextField()

class Follower(Model):
    from_person = ForeignKeyField(Person, related_name='followers')
    to_person = ForeignKeyField(Person, related_name='followed_by')
```