# create Self Referencing Table using peewee

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, peewee

I am failing to find a way I can create a self-referencing table using peewee. I am trying to create an entity similar to one on [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5255964/How-to-Create-and-Use-a-Self-referencing-Hierarchi).

[image]

I have tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47894549/6211470) and it doesn't seem to give me the results that I want.

```
class Customer(Model):
    name = TextField()

class CustomerDepartment(Model):
    refid = ForeignKeyField(Customer, related_name='customer')
    id = ForeignKeyField(Customer, related_name='department')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are documented here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#self-referential-foreign-keys

```
class Department(BaseModel):
    parent = ForeignKeyField('self', null=True, backref='children')
    name = CharField()
```

Example use:

```
root = Department.create(name='root')
d1 = Department.create(parent=root, name='Dept 1')
# etc.
```